# Python, How to write a 2-d array to a binary File with precision (uint8, uint16)?

Tags: python, matlab, binary

I'm hoping someone can explain to me how to write a binary output to a text file.

I know that in matlab, it is pretty simple, as it has the 'fwrite' function which has the following format: fwrite(fileID,A,precision)

However, I'm not sure how to translate this to python. I currently have the data stored in a 2-D numpy array and would like to write it to the file in the same way that matlab does.

I have attempted it with the following:

```
#let Y be the numpy matrix
with open (filepath,'wb') as FileToWrite:
    np.array(Y.shape).tofile(FileToWrite)
    Y.T.tofile(FileToWrite)
```

however, this didn't lead to the desired result. The file size is way to large and the data is incorrectly formatted.
Ideally i should be able to specificy the data format to be uint8 or uint16 as well.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You can use [savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), where you can specifiy the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it. The solution is as follows.

```
#let Y be the numpy matrix
with open (filepath,'wb') as FileToWrite:
    np.asarray(Y, dtype=np.uint8).tofile(FileToWrite)
```